# Look for celebrities linkedIn accounts using google search engine apis

Tags: python, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

Looking for celebrities LinkedIn accounts using google apis - When I visit the bellow link I get the `Json` see bellow. I get users related using some sort of google ranking system but not the actual celebrity I'm looking for.

How do I get only the people who have the name `Stevie Wonder`? exactly where `items.hcard.fn` == `Stevie Wonder` which the bellow link doesn't privide.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="YOUR_KEY"&cx="ENGINE_API"&q="search_term&exactTerms="search_term"&siteSearch=linkedin.com&alt=json



{'context': {'title': 'linkdin-search-projecr'},
 'items': [
           {'displayLink': 'www.linkedin.com',
            'formattedUrl': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ron-taylor-169a0b72',
            'htmlFormattedUrl': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ron-taylor-169a0b72',
            'htmlSnippet': 'During this time I worked exclusively for <b>STEVIE WONDER</b>. His special <br>\nrequirements far exceeds the duties of any other Personal Assistant. I am <br>\npresently his&nbsp;...',
            'htmlTitle': 'RON TAYLOR | LinkedIn',
            'kind': 'customsearch#result',
            'link': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ron-taylor-169a0b72',
            'pagemap': {'cse_image': [{'src': 'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/06b/2ae/35b8ebe.jpg'}],
                        'cse_thumbnail': [{'height': '160',
                                           'src': 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuIo1ZVj9Z6-CozzsMELKt9zBSfvLIprbzV3FA0owQqpxyTcIlIGL0HJy8',
                                           'width': '160'}],
                        'hcard': [{'fn': 'RON TAYLOR',
                                   'photo': 'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/06b/2ae/35b8ebe.jpg',
                                   'title': 'EXECUTIVE PERSONAL ASSISTANT, CHIEF OF SECURITY & LOGISTICS to STEVIE WONDER'}],
                        'metatags': [{'application-name': 'LinkedIn',
                                      'appname': 'chrome',
                                      'detectadblock': '//platform.linkedin.com/js/px.js',
                                      'globaltrackingappid': 'webTracking',
                                      'globaltrackingappname': 'chrome',
                                      'globaltrackingurl': '//www.linkedin.com/mob/tracking',
                                      'lnkd-track-json-lib': 'https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=2jds9coeh4w78ed9wblscv68v-ebbt2vixcc5qz0otts5io08xv',
                                      'msapplication-tilecolor': '#0077B5',
                                      'msapplication-tileimage': 'https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/linkedin/logo-in-win8-tile-144_v1.png',
                                      'og:description': u"View RON TAYLOR\u2019S professional profile on LinkedIn. LinkedIn is the world's largest business network, helping professionals like RON TAYLOR discover inside connections to recommended job candidates, industry experts, and business partners.",
                                      'og:image': 'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/06b/2ae/35b8ebe.jpg',
                                      'og:title': 'RON TAYLOR | LinkedIn',
                                      'pageimpressionid': '-d3-a9',
                                      'pagekey': 'public_profile_v3_desktop',
                                      'referrer': 'origin',
                                      'remotenavjscontentbaseurl': 'https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?v=build-2000_8_56815-prod',
                                      'treeid': 'wrAWT+5EWxRA29Bh1SoAAA=='}],
                        'person': [{'location': 'United States',
                                    'org': 'STEVLAND MORRIS PRODUCTIONS & WONDERLAND STUDIO',
                                    'role': 'EXECUTIVE PERSONAL ASSISTANT, CHIEF OF SECURITY & LOGISTICS to STEVIE WONDER'}]},
            'snippet': u'During this time I worked exclusively for STEVIE WONDER. His special \nrequirements far exceeds the duties of any other Personal Assistant. I am \npresently his\xa0...',
            'title': 'RON TAYLOR | LinkedIn'}
            ],
 'kind': 'customsearch#search',
 'queries': {'nextPage': [{'count': 10,
                           'cx': '',
                           'exactTerms': 'Stevie Wonder',
                           'inputEncoding': 'utf8',
                           'outputEncoding': 'utf8',
                           'safe': 'off',
                           'searchTerms': 'Stevie Wonder',
                           'siteSearch': 'linkedin.com',
                           'startIndex': 11,
                           'title': 'Google Custom Search - Stevie Wonder',
                           'totalResults': '1590'}],
             'request': [{'count': 10,
                          'cx': '',
                          'exactTerms': 'Stevie Wonder',
                          'inputEncoding': 'utf8',
                          'outputEncoding': 'utf8',
                          'safe': 'off',
                          'searchTerms': 'Stevie Wonder',
                          'siteSearch': 'linkedin.com',
                          'startIndex': 1,
                          'title': 'Google Custom Search - Stevie Wonder',
                          'totalResults': '1590'}]},
 'searchInformation': {'formattedSearchTime': '0.31',
                       'formattedTotalResults': '1,590',
                       'searchTime': 0.313269,
                       'totalResults': '1590'},
 'url': {'template': 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json',
         'type': 'application/json'}}
```

at the moment I'm getting the results and checking every `fn` object to see if the name match the search, the issue is that it cost me $$ every time I hit `google search engine API`. I want to eliminate results to small set. I have to visit about 20 page for some cases to check if the name exist in the response. I was wondering if there's a way to only get 100% positive users with the exact name in the fn object

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like the following, if response is the response dict. Of course first you will have to convert the json to dict.

```
response.get('items')[0].get('pagemap').get('hcard')[0].get('fn')
```

Comment: You are correct, I'm doing that at the moment, the issue is that it cost me `$$` every time I hit google search engine API. I want to eliminate results to small set. I have to visit about 20 page for some cases to check if the name exist in the dictionary. I was wondering if there's a way to only get 100% positive users with the exact name in the `fn` object.